# Difference of floating arithmetics on AMD CPUs and Intel CPUs

Tags: c++, floating-point, x86-64, amd-processor

I am student majoring in computational science. When I deal with mixed-precision projects on AMD CPUs, I find that single precision data behaves similarly to double precision data. Sometimes, single-precision data costs even more computation time than double-precision data. But mixed-precision calculations on Intel CPUs perform as expected.

An simplified example:

```
    double a = 1.0/3.0, c = 5.0/7.0;
    float b = 1.0/3.0, d = 5.0/7.0;
    double time4d = omp_get_wtime();
    for(int i = 0;i < 10000000;i ++)
    {
      a = a + c;
    }
    std::cout << omp_get_wtime() - time4d << std::endl;
    double time4f = omp_get_wtime();
    for(int i = 0;i < 10000000;i ++)
    {
      b = float(b) + float(d);
    }

    std::cout << omp_get_wtime() - time4f << std::endl;
```

I'm using g++ with the following flags:

```
-o main -fopenmp -O0 -ffloat-store
```

On the server with AMD EPYC 7713 64-Core Processor, the ouput is:

```
0.0388171
0.0388219
```

However, on the server with Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6136 CPU, the output is:

```
0.0424005
0.0244199
```

I wonder if I missed some flags or operations, making the single-precision not work on AMD CPUs as expectation. What causes such a phenomenon? Furthermore, how can I make the mixed-precision calculations work on AMD CPUs?

Comment: `-O0 -ffloat-store` basically results in an unoptimized, even "pessimized", build, correct? Benchmarking unoptimized code makes no sense, IMHO. What is it you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: First of all, thank you for your comments. This is a part of my project for a course about mixed-precision calculations. The professor told me that some optimizations might make the calculation comparison unfair. So, I use `-O0` here to avoid optimizations(Maybe I misunderstood the course). Following your advice, I change the flag `O0` to `O2`(`O1` still can not work well). Then, the single-precision data costs less CPU time than the double-precision data on AMD CPUs. So, is it better to use the flag `O2` for such comparisons in scientific computations(I am unfamiliar with that)?

Comment: Besides, I'm still confused by the weird performance of single-precision data calculations on AMD CPUs without optimization options. By the IEEE754 standard, the float type costs fewer bits, which should naturally cost less computational time. But here, the single-precision data performs unexpectedly on AMD CPUs.

Comment: [1] Compile with full optimizations, e.g. `-O3`, but with relatively high fidelity to IEEE-754, e.g. `-fp-model=precise`, and avoid "quick & dirty" optimizations, e.g.`-ffast-math`. Add tuning flags for each target architecture. [2] Analyze generated assembly code. [3] Profile code, extracting salient CPU event counters [4] Set what you have glimpsed from steps (1) through (3) in relation to CPU architecture details. Your benchmark posted here is what is known as a synthetic test. These are largely meaningless, benchmark at level of library functions or applications instead.

Comment: Thanks for these precious comments. I will follow your suggestion to implement more numerical experiments. Thanks again!

Comment: For Intel/AMD microarchitectural differences, see https://agner.org/optimize/, specifically his microarch PDF.  And https://uops.info/.  With that, and the compiler-generated asm you tested, you can see what bottlenecks might exist.  (Also [What considerations go into predicting latency for operations on modern superscalar processors?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51607391).

Comment: As njuffa says, benchmarking `-O0` code makes no sense if you want to know how normal efficient code will run; [Why does clang produce inefficient asm with -O0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53366394), but if you want to know exactly why that executable ran at different speeds on different CPUs, there is a reason which can be discovered by looking carefully at the compiler-generated asm (not the source).  It might not be a reason that has anything to do with normal cases of optimized code, though.

Comment: Nobody in their right mind will ship unoptimized code in production. Unoptimized code (`-O0`) exists to aid in debugging by making the debugger produce the expected results when stepping through the source - but the performance is (usually) horrific. C++ depends heavily on compiler optimizations to remove abstractions and otherwise improve the performance of the code you write. For any real-life/production code, any competent programmer would use something like `-O2` or `-O3` (and often also `-flto`) to build their code and that is what you should be testing for performance.

Comment: @PeterCordes The materials are beneficial! I will spend some time on these. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: @JesperJuhl Thanks for your comments. It seems that I misunderstand the meaning of `-O0`. Your response is quite inspiring.